# Display view name or defined identifier in Xcode6 debug log

Tags: ios, xcode

Here is the array of auto-layout errors I get in the log:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7f9060 H:[UIView:0x7b7f8f30(175)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7f9090 UIView:0x7b7f8f30.width == UIView:0x7b7f8f30.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7f90c0 V:[UIView:0x7b7f8f30(50)]>"
)
```

On older Xcode I could set an identifier so that "UIView" would be replaced by the identifier. In Xcode6, I can't find how to do this, so i'm stuck with this hard to understand code where I don't know which views this is about.
Do you know how what I could do in  Xcode6 so I have a way to replace UIView by some text I can understand ?

Comment: How did you set the identifier in the older Xcode?

Comment: In Identity inspector, there was Identity / Identifier field. Which is not there in current version.

Comment: I am not near my Mac at the moment, however that does sound unlikely...

Answer (score 0):

The solution for Xcode 6 is to add the accessibilityIdentifier to the Runtime Attributes. The value defines the name of the view.

[image: Set a User Defined Runtime Attribute]